# scaling actual dimensions to perspective dimensions (on flat surface)? - does the solution have to use integral/derivative?

Tags: trigonometry

Im Johan, new to mathematics stack exchange (second post). How are you?

I draw lots o differnt stuff and do space art with spray paint. Ive been pondering and trying to get perspective right using math. What seemed easy turned out really hard for me.

In photoed papers i wrote distance per angle. But its more like perpendicular distance to line of sight per angle.  [http://imgur.com/a/lQzW0ry](https://imgur.com/a/lQzW0ry)

From looking at notes, am i on the right track at getting a way of scaling actual dimensions to perspective dimensions (on flat surface for example a piece of paper)?

Do you know of a solution that doesnt require derivative/integral? Other options?

Id like to understand and im thinking of repeating some math and learn more for fun and if necessary. But to me drawing is main hobby.

Greetings Johan

Ps dont know where to seperate question from answer. (Same link as in my answer to this question) https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVIc0.jpg

Comment: can you please add a picture showing what you are wanna get? for a better understanding...

Comment: I tried but lack reputation:(

Comment: you can upload an image on other site and share the link here.

Comment: Thx man, will do that but im busy right now

Comment: Hi Rakibul:) does this link work?http://imgur.com/a/lQzW0ry I tried describing what its about. There's 6 light pages (not packed). Glad if you take a look:) thx

Comment: I have several specific attempts as well but not to spam you with paper i didnt post. Also they all come out different, some slightly and i really dont know what im doing;) eager for some feedback:) thx

Answer (score 0):

This is what ive got so far https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVIc0.jpg

To my knowledge, yes it have to be integral, since scale varies non linear

Maybe theres another way to do it, i havent figured out

Greetings Johan

Comment: Hi as i work the problem more question comes up. Most i solve some not and some of them lingers. Should i keep posting in same question about this problem (as a thread) repost problem with slightly new take on it or make it vague by trying to generalize something i dont fully comprehend? /Johan